# Google One Tap SignIn with cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, google-signin

Google is [Discontinuing Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html#:%7E:text=As%20we%20move%20to%20further,it%20on%20March%2031%2C%202023.).
but Cognito is still using the old library.
so how can I implement [One-tap sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) with my react web app?[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito only needs to verify the ID Token ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html)).

To my understanding, this is done using the [Google Auth Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token), which is not getting deprecated. The [Google Sign-In JavaScript Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), which is being deprecated, is a different library.

Comment: From that doc page it looks like you're referring the "Api Summary section"? (Full API Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html)). I think that would let you use the Google Sign in Library, it doesn't feel as if this is the correct approach when using the AWS Amplify libraries for handling the login, as they're abstracting that away. I will take a look though and see if these can be used side-by side or if there's an alternative